# Getting colour of a pixel from Canvas using getImageData giving the wrong colour

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am making a Venn diagram based game and have implemented a flood fill algorithm to fill each region that looks like the below.

[image]

As I don't want to be able to flood fill the outline of the circles I have a check that ensures that if if the edge is clicked on then it isn't filled. This is done by checking that the colour is not red.

```
function circleEdgeClicked(x, y) {
   var colorLayer = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
   var pixelPos = (x * canvasWidth + y) * 4;

   startR = colorLayer.data[pixelPos];
   startG = colorLayer.data[pixelPos + 1];
   startB = colorLayer.data[pixelPos + 2];

   if (startR === 255 && startG === 0 && startB === 0) {
     console.log("Colour is red");
   }

   return (startR === 255 && startG === 0 && startB === 0);
 }
```

The desired behavior is a click will flood fill to yellow and another click will revert by flood filling with white. toHowever, sometimes when clicking inside the circle, either when it is yellow or white the area does not fill to the opposite color. Debugging the cause has shown the issue is because getImageData is incorrectly saying that the pixel clicked on is red.

Here is the code in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ev70uv7/) where the bug can be replicated by just clicking in the circles and after a few tries it will not fill and the logs will say that the colour is red even though it isn't.

In the getImageData documentation there is this note 
`Due to the lossy nature of converting to and from premultiplied alpha color values, pixels that have just been set using putImageData() might be returned to an equivalent getImageData() as different values.`

Does this have anything to do with it and is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line from:

```
var pixelPos = (x * canvasWidth + y) * 4;
```

to

```
var pixelPos = (y * canvasWidth + x) * 4; // or use <<2 instead of * 4
```

so `y` (representing line/stride) and not `x` is multiplied with width.

It would also be faster to either cache the bitmap beforehand, or read a single pixel:

```
var colorLayer = context.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);
```

You may want to do boundary checks for x/y vs. width/height in this case. You can also read it as 32-bit value and compare 0xff0000ff (ABGR) directly assuming there is no alpha, or shift it over removing the alpha:

```
function circleEdgeClicked(x, y) {
   var color = new Uint32Array(context.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data.buffer)[0];
   return (color<<8) === 0xff00;  // is red? ignoring alpha
 }
```

An additional boost will be to grab the bitmap when the red outline is initialized. Since we will prevent filling on top of those you can cache the bitmap in this state and check without transferring a new bitmap each time a pixel needs to be checked (and there is not much memory overhead as the Uint32 view will share the buffer of the original bitmap):

```
// by here the red outlines are drawn, so we grab it at this stage
var pixels =
      new Uint32Array(context.getImageData(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight).data.buffer);

// then reuse the buffer when a pixel needs to be checked
function circleEdgeClicked(x, y) {
   var color = pixels[y * canvasWidth + x];  // all values are 32-bit
   return (color<<8) === 0xff00;  // is red? ignoring alpha
 }
```

About lossy nature: there is that issue, which in some cases which is caused by rounding errors. On top of that, if the source drawing is drawn from an image the bitmap values can be altered by gamma or ICC profiles when loaded.

The workaround is to implement a tolerance, for example for red, accept the value to be in the range of 250-255 instead of exactly 255, blue and green to have a range 0-5 etc. (+/- 5 is arbitrary here, just experiment to find an optimal value). You will also discover that the alpha will need to be considered if the base drawing has a non-opaque background.

Comment: Well put, but still I'd suggest to use .getImageData(x, y, 1, 1) to extract a single pixel. Thats simpler, clearer and less memory consuming than reading a whole canvas.

Comment: This is great! My `circleEdgeClicked` function was taking around ~7ms to execute and yours is far faster. Just out of interest, the first time your function is executed it takes ~3ms then every subsequent call is under 0.1ms. Why are all calls after the first so much faster?

Comment: @JaAnTr the browser is likely able to optimize it the second run - since it involves a bit-shift and integer values those are always good candidates for optimizations. It's also faster to read/compare a full 32-bit value than 3 byte values.

Comment: @LukaKvavilashvili you're absolute right, in most cases, but you can also use this to cache the bitmap beforehand if possible in the given scenario (and it seem to be here) so we can exploit this as well - I added a new section about this (boost add).

Comment: @K3N ABGR for big endian and RGBA for little endian systems. Using Uint32Array should have a endian test or use a Uint32Array to get a known colour and compare to that

Comment: @Blindman67 most systems today (consumer side) are LE unless you're on Motorola 68k/PPC etc. The format here in this case is actually ABGR on LE systems when reading the values as 32-bit ([test](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/66o67f2L)). It's easy to [test for endianess](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/ppu7crLe/) though - if endianess is suspected to be a problem a DataView may be a better in general, but also slower.

Comment: So you are saying big endian is dead.. 

Answer (score 4):

I'm not quite sure, but since pixel data is one dimensional array, in order to transform x, y into an index of an array in pixel data, you have to use

```
(x + canvasWidth * y) * 4
```

Because y position will represent how many lines of horizontal pixels you have to skip to get to the pixel, and that is going to be canvasWidth * y, and then + x for horizontal axis.

Above is just to fix your error, but my suggestion and question is, why don't you just use getImageData straight ahead? [getImageData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) takes x, y, width and height arguments, so you are able to extract a single pixel just by it's position.

```
function circleEdgeClicked(x, y) {
   // will return an array of 4 integers (rgba)
   var colorLayer = context.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);

   startR = colorLayer.data[0];
   startG = colorLayer.data[1];
   startB = colorLayer.data[2];

   if (startR === 255 && startG === 0 && startB === 0) {
     console.log("Colour is red");
   }

   return (startR === 255 && startG === 0 && startB === 0);
 }
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're saying, I am transforming the array with `var pixelPos = (x * canvasWidth + y) * 4;`

Comment: Yes, but in order to transform the x, y coordinates into pixelPos, you have to use (x + canvasWidth * y) * 4 not (x * canvasWidth + y) * 4.

But instead of that, you could just use the getImageData(x, y, 1, 1) to get the exact pixel instead of reading the whole canvas and finding the pixel.